ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient 7.17.21 failed to Index to Elastic 8 server
TL;DR : same elasticsearch index() call seem to generate different request, 7.0.0 generate the proper POST myEs8Server:8299/MyIndex/_doc {}, while 7.17.21 generate a GET myEs8Server:8299/
Without index name and type.
=====More details=====
I'm upgrading springboot 2 app to 3, and migrating ElasticSearch from 7 to 8 at the same time.
Code uses RestHighLevelClient on elasticsearch client java libs v7.0.0. It actually works indexing to both ES 7 and 8. But due to vulnerability issue, we have to upgrade to latest lib 7.17.21. Everytime it calls "index()" or "indexAsync()" or even "exists()", it will fail.
[Run with 7.17.21 lib targeting to index to ES 8 - stacktrace snippet, removed server name]
method [GET], host [http://XXXXX.XXXXX.com:8299], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]\n<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.24.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\n\tat 
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)\n\tat 
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)\n\tat 
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)\n\tat 
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)\n\tat 
org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:1241)
.....

Why it triggers a GET with no subpath on URI? Indeed curling this url will give 404, but it should be POSTing with index name and json body
This works when using 7.0.0 lib, and the index() function generates the right HTTP POST request.
[7.0.0 lib indexing to same ES 8]
Request generated:
{[MyIndex][_doc][null], source[{"module": "vol1","time": "2024-06-07T00:00:00-0400","message": "Test","znodename": "N/A"}]}

Response obtained:
[index=MyIndex,type=null,id=kfWH9I8BFA8m-WWFA6Bk,version=1,result=created,seqNo=485,primaryTerm=1,shards={"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}]

=======Extra note on the code=======
Note: switching between 7.0.0 and 7.17.21 lib requires code changes.
[Creating client in 7.17.21]
client = new RestHighLevelClientBuilder(clientBuilder.build()).setApiCompatibilityMode(true).build();

[Creting client in 7.0.0]
client = new RestHighLevelClient(clientBuilder);

In both 7.0.0/7.17.21, the clientBuilder has setDefaultHeaders ran with the 2 headers:
Accept "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7"
Content-Type "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7"

[Indexing call]
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("MyIndex","_doc");

request.source("{"+
                "\"module\": \"vol1\",\"time\": \"2024-06-07T00:00:00-0400\",\"message\": \"Test\",\"znodename\": \"N/A\"}", XContentType.JSON);

IndexResponse _ir =  client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

I have tried other lib versions, appears that 7.0 7.1 7.2 7.3 works.
It also appears that springboot 2 vs 3 does not make a difference in this case.
Also, I'm on Java 17 when testing both using Eclipse.

_doc is deprecated. Newer versions do not use _doc and omitted the document type in the URL path.

Elasticsearch 7.x
Specifying types in requests is deprecated. For instance, indexing a document no longer requires a document type. The new index APIs are PUT {index}/_doc/{id} in case of explicit ids and POST {index}/_doc for auto-generated ids. Note that in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of the path, and represents the endpoint name rather than the document type.
The include_type_name parameter in the index creation, index template, and mapping APIs will default to false. Setting the parameter at all will result in a deprecation warning.
The default mapping type is removed.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/removal-of-types.html
And this should be without _doc.
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("MyIndex");

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-index.html

Thanks for the tips, however same behaviour when I removed _doc.
